# Unable to Save Due to Record Locking (by Current Machine)

Tags: ms-access

Updated***

To quickly summarize what I said before which was lengthy and probably too roundabout confusing...

My issue was I have a main form interface with 2 subforms that does the following:

1. the First one is always shown for current daily event task(s) based on a label control with current date or any given dates via the prev/next toggle buttons as criteria.
2. The second one is part of the main subform that will be called based on the selection from the main navigation controls. This subform shows all the event tasks that are created in the database.

Both use saved query select statements with a snapshot and no record lock as recordsource in a continuous form. The table source is linked via split database in the same shared network drive and the table itself contains only 8 fields:

- ID (12 chars randomly generated with specific sequence via VBA with no duplicate allowed)
- Event Name (Text)
- Event Desc (Long Text/Memo)
- Occurrence (Text)
- Start Date (Date)
- Selected Day (Text)
- Allow Weekend (Text)
- Active (Boolean)

To edit a selected record, it will be called and populated onto a popup unbound model form via VBA. Here everything works fine as for records with fewer chars found in the Event Desc field. However, for records with a large number of chars (so far those that I noticed with issues were the ones with >4000 chars). I can call and display them fine to the detail view form (unbound) but when making edits, by the time it gets to the updating field for Event Desc, it would generate the record locking error by the same user (me) for those with large text size.

After several trials and errors, I noticed it has to do with the displayed continuous subforms that I have presenting. I noticed that the form for them were originally set as dynaset to which I tried to switch over to snapshot and it was a hit and miss (mostly miss). I don't know how much of this setting was an issue to the record updating as I had no problem saving records with smaller character counts.

Finally, I decided to before saving the record, I went and remove the recordsource for both of the continuous forms to empty ("") then save then reassign the query (saved or direct doesn't matter) and it worked without errors after. I personally don't like doing it this way as it makes the continuous forms update look ugly and not smooth (see the **#Name?**) in the assigned controls due to unrecognized control source since the recordsource is now empty. However, this was the best way that I could think up at the moment.

I even tried using a bounded form for editing the record instead of the unbound form and the same error outcome, but that time it gave a different record locking error# but pretty much for the same reason.

I'm sure this issue is **not** related to how my VBA code was written nor the queries used in the continuous forms. It's most likely the form settings themselves or just some limitation of Access?

Comment: Linked to what - another Access file?

Comment: Yes, it's just a split database and I'm editing the data using a frontend. The backend is located in shared network drive. I've never had this issue before (though I have never really used memo data type due to its size).

Comment: ID is a text type field? Is ID also name of textbox on form? I cannot replicate issue with files on my local drive. I might be able to test with shared drive later.

Comment: Correct, ID is a text field and it is manually assigned. I'm going to do more research tomorrow when back in the office and see. When I debugged it worked, but if I let it run normally it fails most of the time. I'll post back tomorrow on my finding, it was just interesting for me since this is the first time, could be a latency issue?

Comment: Tested with link to file on shared drive. Still cannot replicate issue. My drive is just a few feet away from computer and connected to directly to router.

Comment: Please re-read the main post, I've updated it to properly explain the issue in hope that it makes more sense to you. I also included my resolution/workaround. For now, I'm going to go with that and eventually go back to it to see what I can do better for a smooth transition. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, I am just more confused. Scenario seems completely different and removed code. You are mixing bound and unbound forms in a form/subforms arrangement? Form/subform usually involves multiple tables but you mention only one. Question really not suited to SO anyway. No code, no data, not reproducible.